# Movie about a space cargo transporter escorting the daughter of the president to a space station

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I am looking for a space movie I saw one night on TV, I think it was 2015 or 2016. I don't remember any person's name so it might be difficult. Also searched the entire Wikipedia and Googled a lot but can't find a darn thing. Also the movie looked really modern in quality for that year. The space ships were really well animated.

The intro scene is one of the scenes I mostly remember:
In the beginning of the movie some starships are flying by. The movie is about a space cargo transporter or some kind of that. He once was in a military position, in the conversation he has with someone who is flying by with him states he was "the best from the team", something alike that.

So some minutes into the movie he gets a delivery job of a different kind than usual. He has to pick up a woman and bring her to a space station - from who he does not know that she is actually the daughter of the president from his faction who has to be there in time. I don't remember why exactly but it was important for politics and stuff.

So he picks her up but they have to do a layover on some kind of mining planet to refuel his ship. The guy who refuels his ship knows who the woman is and because he works for the antagonist, after the two start the ship he throws a small tracking device onto it from below, unbeknownst to them. One thing I clearly remember is that the sky on that planet was yellow in color.

The driver tells the woman that they need to go through a more dangerous route if they want to get to the space station in time, the safe route will take much longer.

So they come across a planet or sun (can't exactly remember) with an asteroid belt around it, there they get ambushed by a small team of henchmen hired to kill the two (hence the tracking device). Since he doesn't have weapons on his ship (because it's his cargo transporter) the protagonist tries to shake them off in the asteroid belt in which he succeeds with his superior flying skills from his military career years ago. Now the president's daughter reveals to our hero who she is in reality and why they need to get to their destination in time.

Soon after that they arrive at their destination but then a shootout begins on the station and they find out that behind all this is a dictator who wants to be the new ruler of the universe.

The final battle begins when the protagonist along with the president's daughter fly to the mining planet once again to bring an end to the evil dictator, even his old squad comes to aid to take out the enemy ships in the sky there.

Can't be:

- *Lockout* (has no mining planet, asteroid belt scene, cargo transport, intro scene does not match)
- *Flash Gordon* (I thought I knew the antagonist, but the movie is just too old)
- wasn't a *Star Wars* movie
- was no comedy or parody, so no *Spaceballs* or something like that

I'm really out of ideas. Even if I saw multiple movies, I'd really like to see which they were or at least some of these. Like the mining planet with the yellow sky. Or the asteroid belt scene. I really wish I could remember.

Comment: I can't work out if you're trying to troll us with series of film tropes that match The Fifth Element and Attack of the Clones.

Comment: It does sound like one of those bad SyFy movies, where they take an existing story and randomly change an aspect to make it SyFyish. Moby Dick, only with a dragon instead of a whale; things like that. So I wouldn't be surprised if this was a real movie. _The Driver_ in space!

Comment: sounds like Lockout 100%, but then you said it isnt Lockout.

Comment: FWIW the description matches about 80% to Spaceballs...

Comment: It does indeed sound like a mash up of multiple films. OP mentions that they saw it one **night**. Could they have experienced the phenomenon of falling asleep in the middle of one film, and waking up in the middle of another, having dreamed a plot linking the two aided by the soundtrack that they could still hear? This has really happened to me on several occasions.

Comment: Not trolling. The scene I remember most is the one I described with the tracking device, following the asteroid belt scene.
The movie seemed well animated (more like CG and not stop motion or something). But can't be Starwars I know these by heart // I watch Spaceballs once every quarter year or so, I'd remember if it was that lol. I can guarantee it was NOT Lockout because the protagonist did not have to rescue the woman, he just picked her up because of a sidejob he got to get her a taxi ride to a space station. Also not 5th Element I know that one, there was nothing mystical in this movie

Comment: The plot as described also has some elements in common with the *Star Trek* (original series) episode [*Elaan of Troyius*](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/elaan-of-troyius): a politically important woman is being transported on a starship in order to seal a peace deal  between two warring planets (in this case by her marrying the leader of the other side), and a saboteur from one of the factions tries to stop it happening.

Comment: I'm still in search of this movie or at least a movie where at least one of the key scenes I remember is in. Like the intro scene where he talks with his old comrade, the mining planet with the yellow tinted sky or the chase in the asteroid belt. Mind he had no weapons on his ship, so it could not have been Attack of the Clones .... // Edit: I watched that Star Trek episode and I can confirm that it was not that

Comment: Please do [edit] the additional details you gave when you used an answer to rebut an answer, it would seem likely to help identify the movie you're seeking.

Answer (score 2):

Any chance this could be [Jupiter Ascending](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661/)?

I can't remember much of the plot, and the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Ascending) is a little incoherent (thought I vaguely remember the film being so), but there's a few elements that match:

- it was released in 2015, so may have been on TV in 2016
- it spent a fortune on effects, so matches your "modern in quality" comment
- the transporter character is a former soldier
- the female protagonist is an important heir (although I'm not clear on whether she or the transporter character know this)
- the big baddy wants to take over a dynasty
- according to [this plot summary](https://the-take.com/read/can-the-plot-of-jupiter-ascending-be-explained-in-a-quick-summary), it involves a refinery, and they're aided by the soldier's former colleague
- the only mental impression I have of the film is a hodgepodge of tropes lumped together, which again matches your description, though it's otherwise quite forgettable