# Movie about a space cargo transporter who has to pick up a woman and deliver her to a space station

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I am looking for a space movie I saw one night on TV, I think it was 2015 or 2016. I don't remember any person's name so it might be difficult. Also searched the entire Wikipedia and Googled a lot but can't find a darn thing. Also the movie looked really modern in quality for that year. The space ships were really well animated.

The intro scene is one of the scenes I mostly remember:
In the beginning of the movie some starships are flying by. The movie is about a space cargo transporter or some kind of that. He once was in a military position, in the conversation he has with someone who is flying by with him states he was "the best from the team", something alike that.

So some minutes into the movie he gets a delivery job of a different kind than usual. He has to pick up a woman and bring her to a space station - from who he does not know that she is actually the daughter of the president from his faction who has to be there in time. I don't remember why exactly but it was important for politics and stuff.

So he picks her up but they have to do a layover on some kind of mining planet to refuel his ship. The guy who refuels his ship knows who the woman is and because he works for the antagonist, after the two start the ship he throws a small tracking device onto it from below, unbeknownst to them. One thing I clearly remember is that the sky on that planet was yellow in color.

The driver tells the woman that they need to go through a more dangerous route if they want to get to the space station in time, the safe route will take much longer.

So they come across a planet or sun (can't exactly remember) with an asteroid belt around it, there they get ambushed by a small team of henchmen hired to kill the two (hence the tracking device). Since he doesn't have weapons on his ship (because it's his cargo transporter) the protagonist tries to shake them off in the asteroid belt in which he succeeds with his superior flying skills from his military career years ago. Now the president's daughter reveals to our hero who she is in reality and why they need to get to their destination in time.

Soon after that they arrive at their destination but then a shootout begins on the station and they find out that behind all this is a dictator who wants to be the new ruler of the universe.

The final battle begins when the protagonist along with the president's daughter fly to the mining planet once again to bring an end to the evil dictator, even his old squad comes to aid to take out the enemy ships in the sky there.

Can't be:

- Lockout (has no mining planet, asteroid belt scene, cargo transport, intro scene does not match)
- Flash Gordon (I thought I knew the antagonist, but the movie is just too old)
- wasn't a Star Wars movie
- was no comedy or parody, so no *Spaceballs* or something like that

I'm really out of ideas. Even if I saw multiple movies, I'd really like to see which they were or at least some of these. Like the mining planet with the yellow sky. Or the asteroid belt scene. I really wish I could remember.

Comment: I'm guessing you're the same user who posted [this very similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198579/space-movie-about-a-space-deliverer-escorting-the-daughter-of-the-president-of-a) in 2018, using a different account with the same name...? If so, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way, you'll regain the reputation you earned with the previous account, and you can update the original question, rather than relying on this duplicate.

Comment: sry last time it was an unregistered account iirc, i also tried to restore my password but my emails were not found on this site when i tried to reset my password

Comment: No need to apologise, this happens to quite a few users, and if you follow the instructions provided at the link in my previous comment, it should enable you to regain access to your first account.

Comment: I'll delete this as soon as the two users are merged.